# Scalabiliity with tensorflow

Tags: parallel-processing, tensorflow

All,

I've recently installed tensorflow on our cluster and have been running then MNIST example code to test the installation. I am interested in seeing how tensorflow an increase in the number of CPUs would effect tensorflow's performance. To that end I ran the same example code using different number of cores but it doesn't seem like tensorflow is doing a good job at scaling. 
I found from another stackoverflow question that tensorflow automatically uses all of the available CPU's automatically and assumed it to be true while running the jobs.

Find below the plot of No. of cores vs Time taken. It is a mean of 5 trials with the number of cores going from 1 to 28.
[image]
Any explanation as to why the scaling is so bad? I did not a expect a continuous increase with increase in number of cores as I understand, that communication b/w cores is to be taken into account. But I was expecting to see a 'U-shaped' curve with an optimum number of cores for this particular code.

Appreciate any help I can get on this.

Answer (score 0):

How do you run with different numbers of cores? Tensorflow by default uses two threadpools, each with a number of threads related to the total number of cores in the machine, so what you are seeing there is probably noise and tensorflow is always running with the same number of threads (look at its CPU usage to confirm).

If you want to restrict the number of cores used by tensorflow you can do this via the [config proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L145).